# Дата в формате DD.MM.YYYY javascpipt

Tags: javascript, дата

Как вывести дату в формате 23.05.2020 ?

```js
var D = new Date(Date.now());
D.setDate(D.getDate() + 100);
console.log(D + "");
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var D = new Date();
console.log(('0' + D.getDate()).slice(-2) + '.' + ('0' + (D.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '.' + D.getFullYear());
```

Comment: Разве нет функции для перевода в нужный формат ?

Comment: Есть такая библиотека - moment.js, там такие функции есть. А в чистом js, вроде как, нет

Comment: @Федотов, уже более-менее есть, но формат она не очень ест :(

Answer (score 2):

```js
var d = new Date(2020, 0, 9)

console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit',
}))
```